# Hiding the Android Keyboard in Blazor MAUI when an Input Field is Focused

Tags: android, .net, blazor, maui

I'm using Blazor MAUI for a android app and I'm using Mudblazor as a Ui library. I in the index,razor file I have a Mudnumberfiled

```
<MudNumericField u/ref="PLUSearch"
Placeholder="PLU"
u/bind-Value="barcodeString"
TextChanged="PLUchanged"
HideSpinButtons="true"
OnKeyDown="OnPLUKeyDown"
Immediate="true" />
```

I want to focus on a specific field immediately after rendering a page in my Android application. To achieve this, I've used the `PLUSearch.FocusAsync()` function within the `OnInitializedAsync()` method, which has worked perfectly. However, I'm facing an issue where, after focusing on the field, the Android virtual soft keyboard appears automatically. In this particular case, I don't need the soft keyboard because this field is intended for barcode scanning. Is there a way to set the focus on the field without triggering the soft keyboard to appear simultaneously?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'focus' if not letting input in using keyboard?

Comment: Why you want to focus the input field, if not for letting the user type something? What advantage do you get by setting the focus then?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I'm using this field to scan barcodes using Bluetooth scanner.

Comment: @LasithaLankajeewa - If you are using the bluetooth scanner and don't need to let the user type in, I do not understand why you need to set the focus at all?